# Does there exist a solution for full filesystem revision control where the revision db/repository is remote?

Tags: filesystems, configuration-management, revision-control

### Question:

Is there a good solution out there for revision control on an entire file system? This includes the question "would any of the typical revision control systems out there work for this (git, svn, bzr, etc.)?"

### Use case:

We have filesystem images that represent installs that happen to some of our embedded systems where every last file installed can make a difference. They often require modification in the course of development, debugging, and maintenance. Those changes need to be stored along with who made them, why, and when. We also need to be able to diff the changes, and restore to particular versions.

Revisioning filesystems would sound like a good solution, but likely excluded since they include the history in the file system, the size of which we wouldn't want on our embedded systems, along with the fact that we wouldn't want the revision information ending up on a production machine. Though perhaps there's a solution to get around these problems.

Comment: I asked this on SO a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705169/putting-a-complete-filesystem-into-revision-control

Comment: We can't close as a dupe across sites, so I'm closing it as OT as the next closest thing.